# Understanding master spt values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have taking over a project and I have for the live me no idea why this piece of code is here. I understand the view ok but not this seciton as its causing the query to fail at a certain point.

```
SELECT pp.productionplanid,
       pp.weekstartdate,
       pp.weekenddate,
       ppi.productionplanitemid,
       ppi.soporderreturnlineid,
       bat.productionplanbatchid,
       sop.documentno,
       cust.customeraccountname,
       bat.NAME   AS BatchName,
       si.itemid,
       si.code    AS StockCode,
       si.NAME    AS StockName,
       sopLine.allocatedquantity,
       o.quantity AS LineQty
FROM   fuel_productionplan pp
       LEFT JOIN fuel_productionplanitem ppi
              ON pp.productionplanid = ppi.productionplanid
       LEFT JOIN fuel_productionplanbatch ppb
              ON ppi.productionplanbatchid = ppb.productionplanbatchid
       LEFT JOIN soporderreturnline sopLine
              ON ppi.soporderreturnlineid = sopLine.soporderreturnlineid
       LEFT JOIN soporderreturn sop
              ON sopLine.soporderreturnid = sop.soporderreturnid
       LEFT JOIN slcustomeraccount cust
              ON sop.customerid = cust.slcustomeraccountid
       LEFT JOIN stockitem si
              ON sopLine.itemcode = si.code
       LEFT JOIN fuel_productionplanbatch bat
              ON ppi.productionplanbatchid = bat.productionplanbatchid
       LEFT JOIN fuel_boxed boxed
              ON sopLine.soporderreturnlineid = boxed.sopitemlineid
                 AND pp.productionplanid = boxed.productionplanid
       CROSS apply (SELECT 1
                    FROM   master..spt_values v
                    WHERE  v.type = 'P'
                           AND v.number < ( sopLine.allocatedquantity -
                                            Isnull(boxed.qtyboxed, 0) )
                   ) o(quantity)
WHERE  sopLine.allocatedquantity > 0
```

Its this here  portion that fails but for some reason it affects my data I have never seen the following used before master..spt_values.

```
CROSS apply
(
       SELECT 1
       FROM   master..spt_values v
       WHERE  v.type = 'P'
       AND    v.number < (sopline.allocatedquantity - isnull(boxed.qtyboxed, 0))
) o(quantity)
```

Can someone explain to me what is the spt_values is that a function in sql server and how to better If I take out the cross apply I find the item in question but I am worried what V.number is doing and why the original programmer would have used that ?

As suggested I ran the subquery to see what it produced and it produced the following but I dont understand why its braking my data return.

[image]

**Edit 2**

I believe what i need to do is just get the result of this

```
(sopLine.AllocatedQuantity - ISNULL(boxed.QtyBoxed, 0))) o(Quantity)
```

As the column LineQty is there not an easier way of doing this without this complexity.

**Edit 3**

When I remove that cross apply and just display the two columns can someone then please tell me how the cross join is braking the data being returned.

[image]

**Edit 4**

When I attempt to do just the following in replacment of the cross join it does not work.

```
sopLine.AllocatedQuantity - boxed.QtyBoxed AS LineQty
```

**Edit 5**

This is my replacment query which appears to work but is it safe is checking for null good enough.

```
SELECT        pp.ProductionPlanID, pp.WeekStartDate, pp.WeekEndDate, ppi.ProductionPlanItemID, ppi.SOPOrderReturnLineID, bat.ProductionPlanBatchID, sop.DocumentNo, 
                         cust.CustomerAccountName, bat.Name AS BatchName, si.ItemID, si.Code AS StockCode, si.Name AS StockName, sopLine.AllocatedQuantity, boxed.QtyBoxed, 
                         ISNULL(sopLine.AllocatedQuantity - boxed.QtyBoxed, 0) AS LineQty
FROM            dbo.FUEL_ProductionPlan AS pp LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.FUEL_ProductionPlanItem AS ppi ON pp.ProductionPlanID = ppi.ProductionPlanID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.FUEL_ProductionPlanBatch AS ppb ON ppi.ProductionPlanBatchID = ppb.ProductionPlanBatchID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.SOPOrderReturnLine AS sopLine ON ppi.SOPOrderReturnLineID = sopLine.SOPOrderReturnLineID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.SOPOrderReturn AS sop ON sopLine.SOPOrderReturnID = sop.SOPOrderReturnID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.SLCustomerAccount AS cust ON sop.CustomerID = cust.SLCustomerAccountID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.StockItem AS si ON sopLine.ItemCode = si.Code LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.FUEL_ProductionPlanBatch AS bat ON ppi.ProductionPlanBatchID = bat.ProductionPlanBatchID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.FUEL_Boxed AS boxed ON sopLine.SOPOrderReturnLineID = boxed.SopItemLineID AND pp.ProductionPlanID = boxed.ProductionPlanID
WHERE        (sopLine.AllocatedQuantity > 0)
```

In particular this line from above.

```
  ISNULL(sopLine.AllocatedQuantity - boxed.QtyBoxed, 0) AS LineQty
```

Comment: why don't you try that sub-query yourself `SELECT * FROM master..spt_values v WHERE v.type = 'P'` see what does it return

Comment: @Squirrel thanks please see above edit its braking the return of my data I showed the production of the above sub query .

Comment: I imagine the author was using `spt_values` in replacement for a *good* tally table.

Comment: It appears to be out of sync though as their is no data being returned for a specific product and i cant understand why.

Comment: Although some folks use the undocumented `master..spt_values` table as a substitute for a user-defined tally table, I suggest a user-defined table instead since [that may block upgrades and migration to Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/remove-references-to-undocumented-system-tables).

Comment: How would i get the result of the (sopLine.AllocatedQuantity - ISNULL(boxed.QtyBoxed, 0))) o(Quantity) as an extra coulmn i do not beleive i need the tally table at all.

Comment: It's being used as a tally table. Basically, it's "for this computed quantity, return that many rows, and set the quantity value to 1 in the output". It's basically exploding summary information into one row per individual item.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can you explain a bit futher how to

Comment: Is there a way can do this without this table guys thanks cause its braking the system at present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both myself and `Dan` have mentioned a tally table. At it's simplest (lets call it `Numbers`) it just contains a single column (lets call it `number`). Each row of that table contains a distinct integer value. In this case, a subset of rows from the undocumented table `master..spt_values` is being used in its place.

So, create such a tally table, and the query (if the logic is correct) now becomes:

```
CROSS APPLY                     
  (SELECT 1 FROM Numbers
    WHERE
     Numbers.number < (sopLine.AllocatedQuantity - ISNULL(boxed.QtyBoxed, 0))
  ) o(Quantity)
```

(This assumes that your tally table starts at 0. If it starts at 1, use `<=` instead of `<`. If it contains negative numbers as well, also add `Numbers.number >=0` as an extra condition)

As I said in a comment below your question, the logic here seems to be that if `(sopLine.AllocatedQuantity - ISNULL(boxed.QtyBoxed, 0))` is, say, 6, we want to `cross apply` to generate 6 *rows* in the result set, and set their `Quantity` value to 1.

Comment: Any idea why i might be finding a product when i remove that statement all together is their something needs to be run to keep the tally table in line.

Comment: @david - it's purpose is to *multiply* up the existing set of rows produced by the preceding `JOIN`s. So of course you'll have rows without the `CROSS APPLY`, just not (apparently) as *many* as are wanted.

Comment: sorry i just dont understand it as not come across it before is there anyway making above more safe that it will always return a product then i just dont get how its braking. when i look at the product it has allocatedQuantity as 1

Comment: @david - what about `QtyBoxed`? If that's larger than or equal to `AllocatedQuantity` then this will indeed produce zero rows from that original row. If you do need such a row in your output, change `CROSS APPLY` to `OUTER APPLY`. Such rows will have a `NULL` `o.Quantity` column.

Comment: Is there anyway to defend against that damien.

Comment: It should never be larger it is controlled by sage thankfully